# Javascript: Using onmouseover and onmouseout functions on more than one image

Tags: javascript

Edit: Sorry if I reply late to any solutions because I need time to figure out how they work haha

I am a beginner in Javascript and I am currently trying to use this piece of code to change an image on mouseover

```
// Mouseover change (Ciel):
function rollover(my_image){
    my_image.src = "images/ci2_a.png";
    }

function mouseaway(my_image){
    my_image.src = "images/ci_a.png";
    }
```

and this is the corresponding HTML

```
<img src="images/ci_a.png" onmouseover="rollover(this)" onmouseout="mouseaway(this)" alt="xxx" style="float:left; width:38%">
```

This works fine, but I want to do it for more than one image on the same page (a different image rollover for each picture) . Even after changing the name of the functions and stuff  it doesn't work. The first image stops changing onmouseover immediately when I try to add a similar function for the next image. Could someone tell me how to perform similar events on more than one image (not concurrently)? Thank you!

Comment: do you want to add the same image to all elements or different images for different element?

Comment: Could use CSS to avoid the the `onmouse*` functions.

Comment: different images for different elements! sorry if i wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could add event listeners to all the image elements you'd like.

```
<img class="my-image" src="images/ci_a.png" onmouseover="rollover(this)" onmouseout="mouseaway(this)" alt="xxx" style="float:left; width:38%"/>

function rollover(){
  this.src = "images/ci2_a.png";
}

function mouseaway(){
  this.src = "images/ci_a.png";
}

const myImages = document.querySelectorAll('.my-image')
myImages.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', rollover)
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseaway)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the image file as the second parameter like this:

```
function rollover(element, image) {
  element.src = image
}

...
<img onmouseover="rollover(this, 'images/ci2_a.png')" ...>
```

But my question is why do you need JavaScript for that? You can use a simple CSS to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need different images on load and on hover, you need a single way to define this functionality across a collection of images.

Building on Matthew's approach, here's a way to do that.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/7r21jtms/2/) to test it real-time.

You'll dynamically generate the images using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the alternate (hover) image URL.

```
<img class="pics" src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/100" 
    data-swap="https://picsum.photos/id/10/100">
<br>
<img class="pics" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100" 
    data-swap="https://picsum.photos/id/11/100">
<br>
<img class="pics" src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100" 
    data-swap="https://picsum.photos/id/12/100">
<br>
<img class="pics" src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/100" 
    data-swap="https://picsum.photos/id/14/100">
```

Then define the [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for all elements with the class `pics`. Here's a list of all the [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) that can be referenced.

- On `mouseover`, store the original image in a `data` element `original`.
- Then change the `src` with the value of the `data-swap`.
- On `mouseout`, replace the `src` with the original value.

```
const myImages = document.querySelectorAll('.pics')
myImages.forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        img.dataset.original = img.src;
        img.src = img.dataset.swap;
    });
    img.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        img.src = img.dataset.original;
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for! and thank you for the example you gave on JSfiddle as well. I really appreciate the effort :))